# SOQL sub query will not work

Tags: soql

My `GC_Employee_Action__c` object has two lookup relationships to the parent `Employee__c` object, eg: 1 lookup for employee and 2 lookup for his manager who also is an employee.

I have the following query :

```
Select Id, Name (Select Id, Close_Date__c from GC_Employee_Actions__r) From Employee__c
```

While my Employee objects have actions (`GC_Employee_Action__c`) assigned to them I cannot retrieve these actions. Is there the possibility that the sub query does not work because of the double lookup relationship from `GC_Employee_Action__c` to `Employee__c`?

Comment: If you literally copy-pasted the query it's just a matter of putting a comma after Name: `Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Close_....` The two child relationships will have different names, you can find them on the properties screen of the lookup field. You can use them both in queries.

Comment: No I am sorry my fault. The syntax is correct I just forgot the , here.

Comment: In that case, look up the name of the child relationship that you actually want to query for, and make sure you have the proper name in your query.

Comment: Let's save some time here. Add a screenshot of the lookup field definition and let us know the error you are getting.

Comment: I am not getting an error, that is the problem. I wish I got. It just does not return records that i know they exist there. I have checked everything as far as names and relationships are concerned and not only me. I just hoped it has happened to someone else before and found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Inner query needs to be formated as field:

```
SELECT Id, 
   (SELECT Id FROM Contacts)
FROM Account
```

Since relationship is like field/param for SObject

Comment: No I am sorry my fault. The syntax is correct I just forgot the , here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in your query

```
Select Id, Name (Select Id, Close_Date__c from GC_Employee_Actions__r) From Employee__c
```

Make sure that you have given proper relationship name "GC_Employee_Actions__r"

go to child object object definition page i.e ( GC_Employee_Action__c ) click on lookup field which u have created to Employee there you see what is the relation ship name then use that

Comment: The problem is that this is only a sub query of a much larger query and I have to go from parent to child. I tried everything in workbench it just does not work. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

To explain it perfectly lets assume i have two Account lookup relationship fields in Contact object.

[image]

So now i have 3 relationship fields in Contact which points to Account. Just like that, Account have 3 related lists of Contact. If you open up each of the Account relationship field in Contact you will get the following screens.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The following sub queries are valid

```
select id,(select id from contacts) from account
select id,(select id from contacts1__r) from account
select id,(select id from contacts2__r) from account
```

Note there is no __r reference in sub query for contacts as the relationships are standard and the other two are custom.

To come to your question, you should open the two relationship fields and use the appropriate child relationship name with __r.

Hope it helps.